# multiple errors with different positions using megaparsec

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I'm going to use megaparsec for parsing a programming language for university project. However, I searched for finding a way to report multiple errors.

I know about withRecovery and I saw [this](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/43) issue but I didn't find about the case where errors happen on different positions.

for example in this java code :

```
class A
{ 
    public get() // line 3 column 10
    {
        return x // line 5 column 22
    }
}
```

There are error1 "expected type at line 3 column 10" and error2 "missing semicolon at line 5 column 22"

I know I can combine error messages with `failure` but how about multiple positions ? How do I do that ?

Comment: [Here's](https://mrkkrp.github.io/megaparsec/tutorials/fun-with-the-recovery-feature.html) a blog post about the introduction of `withRecovery`.

Comment: @Alec thanks , I saw it but it makes ParseError part of the result of the parser, when you call `runParser` it will return `Either (ParseError ...) (Either (ParseError ...) a)` which seems kind of ugly to me ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure about Alec's suggestion, but don't want to have `Either (ParseError ...) (Either (ParseError ...) a)`, you can just use Control.Monad.join on that value to turn it into an `Either (ParseError ...) a`. Sorry if this wasn't too helpful