# How to report multiple errors using megaparsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

Per megaparsec docs, ["Since version 8, reporting multiple parse errors at once has become much easier."](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec#error-messages) I haven't been able to find a single example of doing it. The only one I find is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180330010428/https://markkarpov.com/megaparsec/fun-with-the-recovery-feature.html). However it only shows how to parse a newline delimited toy language and also does not show how to [combine multiple errors](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/359) into ParseErrorBundle. This [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667592/multiple-errors-with-different-positions-using-megaparsec/39694250) is not conclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `withRecovery` to recover from Megaparsec-generated errors in conjunction with `registerParseError` (or `registerFailure` or `registerFancyFailure`) to "register" those errors (or your own generated errors) for delayed processing.

At the end of the parse, if no parse errors have been registered, then parsing succeeds, while if one or more parse errors have been registered, they are all printed at once.  If you register parse errors and then also trigger an unrecovered error, parsing immediately terminates and the registered errors and the final unrecovered error will all be printed.

Here's a very simple example that parses a comma-separated list of numbers:

```
import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

type Parser = Parsec Void String

numbers :: Parser [Int]
numbers = sepBy number comma <* eof
  where number = read <$> some digitChar
        comma  = recover $ char ','
        -- recover to next comma
        recover = withRecovery $ \e -> do
          registerParseError e
          some (anySingleBut ',')
          char ','
```

On good input:

```
> parseTest numbers "1,2,3,4,5"
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and on input with multiple errors:

```
> parseTest numbers "1.2,3e5,4,5x"
1:2:
  |
1 | 1.2,3e5,4,5x
  |  ^
unexpected '.'
expecting ','

1:6:
  |
1 | 1.2,3e5,4,5x
  |      ^
unexpected 'e'
expecting ','

1:12:
  |
1 | 1.2,3e5,4,5x
  |            ^
unexpected 'x'
expecting ',', digit, or end of input
```

There are some subtleties here.  For the following, only the first parse error is handled:

```
> parseTest numbers "1,2,e,4,5x"
1:5:
  |
1 | 1,2,e,4,5x
  |     ^
unexpected 'e'
expecting digit
```

and you have to study the parser carefully to see why.  The `sepBy` successfully applies the `number` and `comma` parser in alternating sequence to parse `"1,2,"`.  When it gets to `e`, it applies the `number` parser which fails (because `some digitChar` requires at least one digit char).  This is an unrecovered error, so parsing ends immediately with no other errors registered, so only the one error is printed.

Also, if you dropped the `<* eof` from the definition of `numbers` (e.g., to make it part of a larger parser), you'd discover that:

```
> parseTest numbers "1,2,3.4,5"
```

gives a parse error on the period, but:

```
> parseTest numbers "1,2,3.4"
```

parses fine.  On the other hand:

```
> parseTest numbers "1,2,3.4\n hundreds of lines without commas\nfinal line, with comma"
```

gives parse errors on the period and the comma at the end of the file.

The issue is that the `comma` parser is used by `sepBy` to determine when the comma-separated list of numbers has ended.  If the parser succeeds (which it can do via recovery, gobbling up hundreds of lines to the next comma), `sepBy` will try to keep running; if the parser fails (both initially, and because the recovery code can't find a comma after scanning the entire file), `sepBy` will complete.

Ultimately, writing recoverable parsers is kind of tricky.